# there is need to verify IID of dataset and perform statistical test for identical distribution after training and test data split?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, training-data, statistical-test

I know most of all machine learning algorithms were based on the assumption that input data is IID(independently identical distribution). Therefore, we usually do not perform a statistical test to compare statistics of test and training data.

In practice, strictly, we cannot guarantee that the data split identically distributed.
By not checking the distribution of two data sets, concept shift(or data shift) occur. 
So, our model cannot perform accurately.
however, most of all website posts and textbooks do not cover this.

there is need to verify IID and perform statistical comparison after training and test data split?
e.g. two-sample test to compare mean of training data set and test dataset

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumptions that you intial data (before splitting) is IID and that it is large, you can proove that the split induced by a random split is also IID, this can be seen intuitively by the fact that if the test data, that you obtain after the split, is an iid sample drawn from the intial data, and thus it has the same momentum at any order of this data and thus they have the same distribution, the fact that it is independant is related to the sampling processus it self, that draw sample independtly. Now for the case where you have a small dataset, this is not true any more, in that case a lot of people well do some other train_test splits, maybe the most famous and simple is to use a stratified split, i.e. you split data well reserving the proportion of the classes, you can do this by setting the parameter `stratify=True` if you are using `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`. For sure this technique doesn't unsure that the distribution of the inputs is similar between train and test, but at least it ensures that the distribution of labels is similar.